# Nouns as verbs, Brits and Yanks: ID cards

Tags: american-english, british-english, colloquialisms

I find it interesting that not only do British and American English speakers both use the noun 'ID card' as a verb in the context of (trying to be in a position of) purchasing age-restricted items, but abbreviate it differently:

British speakers:

> "The bartender ID'd me"

American speakers:

> "The bartender carded me"

Which do we prefer? Any other similar examples?

Personally I think 'to ID' makes more sense, since although in 'ID card' it's an acronym for 'identity', it easily transforms into 'to ID' -> 'to identify', which makes sense.

But then, I'm British!

Edit:

As @DavidM points out, American speakers say "I got ID'd" to mean "I was [literally] identified" - in a police line-up for instance. If a Briton says "I got ID'd", he more than likely means "I was asked to show some form of ID".

Comment: We would typically say *bouncer* or *guy at the door* in America, not *door guy*.

Comment: Sorry, I'll just remove that reference, as it's not the focus of sentence

Comment: Surely what the bartender does however is check your age through the card rather than identify who you are through the card?

Comment: @virmaior If that were the case, when I was 16 I could have brought my father's drivers license and drank freely. He has to check that the ID says that you are the same of-age person in the picture.

Comment: yes but the point isn't to learn who you are but rather whether you are a person of sufficient age.

Comment: Why do they check your ID when renting a car?  They want to know you have a valid driver's license. Does this mean they don't care it is *your* valid driver's license?  Of course they care. So they ID you as an integral process of validating your license.

Comment: @virmaior The dumbest part of this argument is that we both accept carded as the preferred terminology.  We're arguing secondary usage which no English speaker would be confused by.

Comment: Ollie Ford, that's a strange question considering that the UK does not have ID cards, like other countries do.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the other answerer,

I would say that in my experience as a use of AmE that Americans refer to the practice of having one's identification materials (whether driver's license or passport) checked for sufficient age or right to use services as **carded**. **carded** = someone has doubted the validity of one detail of who I am that is not identifying and requested proof relative to this. (they want my age, height, nationality)

Conversely, we use the verb **ID'd** to refer to the use of these papers for the sake of identification of the person in question. **ID'd** = someone now knows my *identity*. (they want my name, passport number, social security number)

Thus,

> I got carded at the bar
>
> I got carded at the cigar shop

But

> I got ID'd by the witness as the murderer
>
> I got ID'd by the check-in agent
>
> I got ID'd by the government's cameras

Or at least that's how I've heard it used in the Midwest (IN, IL), West (CA), and East Coast (NY / NJ)

Comment: What do you assume they are doing when they check the license?  If they just checked the age, I could have a really successful fake ID business going. Not to mention the signs on the doors of drug stores that say "We ID" with regard to buying cigarettes.

Comment: I just googled We I.D. and came up with tons of hits for signs. We Card is one major company that makes decals, but many others say We I.D. in an identical sense.

Comment: @DavidM They are trying to **confirm** the age of the person they are looking at. This does involve trying to figure out if that person is the same as the one holding the card but ultimately means they want to know the age of the person -- not their identity. They don't care what your name is.

Comment: They don't care beyond a passing 45 seconds. But they care to know it's the same person. Identity is more than your name. Weak argument.

Comment: [I think you'd accept Anheuser-Busch as a reasonable authority on this usage](http://anheuser-busch.com/index.php/our-responsibility/alcohol-responsibility-our-families-our-roads/underage-drinking-prevention/we-i-d/) even if their beer is nigh un-drinkable.

Comment: Obviously they check the photograph on the license, but when the principal question is age, I think _carded_ is far more frequent. Perhaps Budweiser had to take its second choice because "[We Card](http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20130905005314/en/Card-Program-Enters-18th-Year-Calls-Accelerated#.Uwr5dkJdWYA)" was already taken for an anti-tobacco group.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually incorrect.  I'm an American English speaker and we say both carded and ID'd.

In the American sense:

*I got carded* is what underaged college students trying to buy beer say.   With only slightly less frequency, we will also say *I got ID'd.*

In general, IDing is confirming identity for any variety of reasons.  But, carding typically only refers to checking the driver's license.

[This is a link to Anheuser-Busch's We I.D. program.  You don't get much more American than A-B.](http://anheuser-busch.com/index.php/our-responsibility/alcohol-responsibility-our-families-our-roads/underage-drinking-prevention/we-i-d/)

Comment: Ah - right, I forgot about that use of 'IDing'. I was referring to checking ID for purchasing age restricted items, however. I shall edit accordingly.

Comment: @OllieFord We do actually say Id'd in the same sense as carded, though.  Just the more popular slang is to say carded.

Comment: @OllieFord I've edited accordingly, too.

Comment: I take *I got ID'd* to mean something equivalent to *I got made* or they recognized who I was rather than they requested my identification material and used that to judge my age and suitability for drinks or smokes.

Comment: @vitmaior That is absolutely true. My original edit was to that effect.   But, as the OP entirely put the question in terms of a bar bouncer. Yes, I've certainly heard people say ID'd, even though carded is the preferred slang.

Comment: Acknowledged this in edit to OP.

Answer (score 1):

We use ID in America.

Actually, to say you were "carded" is a bit low class, IMO. If the bar is nice, they ID you. For real!

Carding is a fairly recent colloquialism, within the last 25 years or so. We always used to say ID.

Comment: This does not match my experience. Plus, I'd rather you not call me “low class.” ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've not come across 'carded' in London, at least. It doesn't mean it's not used, but 'ID'd' is synonymous to 'security checked' or 'age-verified'. As you point out, it gains homophonic points over 'carded' in its links to 'identified'. 'Carded' gains metaphorical points over 'ID'd', though. I wouldn't be surprised if it became more prevalent over here within 7 years at the outside.

Comment: Neither have I, as I said in OP..